# python: get constructor to return an existing object instead of a new one

Tags: python, constructor

I have a class that knows its existing instances. Sometimes I want the class constructor to return an existing object instead of creating a new one.

```
class X:
    def __new__(cls, arg):
        i = f(arg)
        if i:
            return X._registry[i]
        else:
            return object.__new__(cls)
    # more stuff here (such as __init_, _registry, etc.)
```

Of course, if the first branch is executed, I don't need `__init__`, but it's invoked anyways. What's a good way to tell `__init__` to do nothing?

I can probably just add some attribute to keep track of whether `__init__` has run yet, but perhaps there's a better way?

Comment: You don't need a constructor. You need a factory method. For exactly this reason is why many argue constructors should be private and you should (nearly) always go through a factory method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a factory, i.e.

```
_x_singleton = None

def XFactory():
    global _x_singleton

    if _x_singleton is None:
        _x_singleton = X()
    return _x_singleton
```

or use a "create" classmethod in your class that behaves the way you want it to,

```
class X(object):
    instance = None
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
    @classmethod
    def create(cls):
        if cls.instance is None:
            cls.instance = cls()
        return cls.instance
```

You might even consider making `__init__` raise an exception if some condition isn't met (i.e. self.instance not being None)

Comment: I personally find this much less confusing than when someone's overridden the standard behaviour with magic. You can ensure that `__init__` isn't *accidentally* called by passing the factory in as one of its arguments.

Answer (score 11):

In languages that support private constructors (C#, Dart, Scala, etc), factory methods provide a robust solution to this problem.

In Python, however, class constructors are always accessible, and so a user of your class may easily forget the factory method and call the constructor directly, producing duplicate copies of objects that should be unique.

A fool-proof solution to this problem can be achieved using a metaclass. The example below assumes that the zeroth constructor argument can be used to uniquely identify each instance:

```
class Unique(type):

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if args[0] not in cls._cache:
            self = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            cls.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            cls._cache[args[0]] = self
        return cls._cache[args[0]]

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attributes):
        super().__init__(name, bases, attributes)
        cls._cache = {}
```

It can be used as follows:

```
class Country(metaclass=Unique):
    def __init__(self, name: str, population: float, nationalDish: str):
        self.name = name
        self.population = population
        self.nationalDish = nationalDish

placeA = Country("Netherlands", 16.8e6, "Stamppot")
placeB = Country("Yemen", 24.41e6, "Saltah")
placeC = Country("Netherlands", 11, "Children's tears")

print(placeA is placeB)    # -> False
print(placeA is placeC)    # -> True
print(placeC.nationalDish) # -> Stamppot
```

In summary, this approach is useful if you want to produce a set of unique objects at runtime (possibly using data in which entries may be repeated).